# http Request with array[long] body in RESTSHARP

Tags: c#, restsharp

Jarray i is read from file and this is the content:
[915417, 915418, 915419]

Here is my code:
JArray i = HELPERS_Read_InputJArray_File(input, strEdit);

```
        IRestResponse resp = null;
        IRestRequest request = null;
        var auth = "Bearer " + api.accessToken;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = c.mySiteUri;

        //body setup
        try
        {
            request = new RestRequest(api.HTTPRequestAPI, Method.POST);

            request.AddHeader("Authorization", auth);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            request.AddParameter("application/json", i, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            resp = client.Execute(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
        }
```

The problem is it compiled and returned 200 but it did not work.

Comment: what do you mean by `did not work`?

Comment: I am not getting the correct result in our DB. I figure out what the problem is.  The code above is correct. The problem was the guid I am reading is from the wrong data. I was blaming my code, first. So I figured to read the correct data and everything worked. I learn from this experience for sure. I was banging my head blaming my code for weeks.